# Копия state в Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

До недавнего времени делал копию **state** с помощью выражения `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))` и не о чём не парился. Но узнал, что это неверный подход. Толкового объяснения не получил.

Если это так, то почему?

Comment: А зачем вы делаете копию state?

Comment: @PashaPash♦, разве в редьюсерах этого делать не надо? Когда я что-то диспатчу

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко можно по конкретнее?

Comment: естественно, не надо. в редьюсерах нужно собирать *новый* стейт на основе предыдущего + данных из action. для этого есть стандартный синтаксис - [spread operator](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator), который делает поверхностую копию, и позволяет заменить одно свойство. А что, что вы делаете - преобразование в строку и потом обратно в объекты всего стейта - дикий оверхед. Работать будет, но медленно и с кучей мусора в памяти на каждый диспатч.

Comment: @PashaPash♦ , спасибо за развернётый ответ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Приходишь с девушкой в ресторан, просишь официанта вино. Тебе приносят кифир. Ну, пьется же?

Безусловно, ваш способ работает, но бьет по глазу, так как приведение к строке. Кроме того, JSON.stringify() не сохраняет функции, помещенные в поля объекта. Это тоже не верное использование Redux, но всё же...

Документация Redux [предлагает](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator) использовать либо Object.assign(),

```
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return Object.assign({}, state)
...
```

либо object spread syntax

```
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return { ...state }
...
```